# windbg !vprot vs !address

Tags: debugging, memory, windbg

running `!vprot` and `!address` on the same address(0x00973ee8), but get different result. What is the difference between `!vprot` and `!address`?

```
0:001> !vprot 0x00973ee8

BaseAddress:       0000000000973000

AllocationBase:    0000000000970000

RegionSize:        **0000000000005000**


0:001> !address 0x00973ee8

Allocation Base:        00000000`00970000

Base Address:           00000000`00970000

End Address:            00000000`00978000

Region Size:            **00000000`00008000**
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!vprot` provides RegionSize for `Specific page`
`!address` provides RegionSize for the `whole Commit`

a sample python script as an example

```
:\>type vproadd.py
from ctypes import *
class MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION (Structure):

    _fields_ = [
        ("BaseAddress",  c_ulong),
        ("AllocationBase", c_ulong),
        ("AllocationProtect", c_long),
        ("RegionSize", c_long),
        ("State", c_long),
        ("Protect", c_long),
        ("Type", c_long)    ]
mem = windll.kernel32.VirtualAlloc(0,0x30000,0x3000,0x40)
print "Allocation Base 0x%08X" % mem
oldprot = c_ulong();
windll.kernel32.VirtualProtect(mem+0x3000,0x3000,0x02,byref( oldprot))
protdet = MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION()
for i in range (0,0x8000,0x1000):
        windll.kernel32.VirtualQuery((mem+i),byref(protdet),sizeof(protdet))
        print "PageNo %02d BaseAddress 0x%08X regionsize 0x%08X protection %02d" % (
        i/4096, protdet.BaseAddress,protdet.RegionSize ,protdet.Protect)
windll.kernel32.VirtualFree(mem,0,0x8000)

:\>python vproadd.py
Allocation Base 0x00510000
PageNo 00 BaseAddress 0x00510000 regionsize 0x00003000 protection 64
PageNo 01 BaseAddress 0x00511000 regionsize 0x00002000 protection 64
PageNo 02 BaseAddress 0x00512000 regionsize 0x00001000 protection 64
PageNo 03 BaseAddress 0x00513000 regionsize 0x00003000 protection 02
PageNo 04 BaseAddress 0x00514000 regionsize 0x00002000 protection 02
PageNo 05 BaseAddress 0x00515000 regionsize 0x00001000 protection 02
PageNo 06 BaseAddress 0x00516000 regionsize 0x0002A000 protection 64
PageNo 07 BaseAddress 0x00517000 regionsize 0x00029000 protection 64
```